# Homomorphic image of a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Through I'm reading a paper "Chain conditions in modules with krull dimension
Dilek Pusat-Yilmaz &Patrick F. Smith", I confused with the meaning of 'primitive homomorphic image' phrase. Through researching I understood that by a homomorphic image of a ring we mean $R/I,~I\subset R $. My question, Is  primitive homomorphic image mean $I$ is primitive?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you mention “I read in a paper” then you should also say *what* paper.  Why would you hold back information if you really want to know?